# How can I best retest a bug in a newer or development release?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

I have reported a bug that occurs in Karmic on launchpad, and I have been asked to re-test it on lucid or maverick. How can I do this best?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For testing Maverick, `testdrive` is easiest. It'll automatically download the latest Maverick daily and run it in a Virtual Machine.

```
sudo apt-get install testdrive virtualbox-ose
testdrive
```

Comment: Good answer for most bugs. However, if it's a bug that is specific to your hardware, testdrive will not help. In this case, use one of the test build ISOs as a live CD - see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/ISO .

Comment: Yes.. this is a good point

Answer (score 9):

Three routes:

- Install Ubuntu in a VM.

  **Pros:** Your installation is persistent, and you can switch back and forth between the VM and your normal desktop with ease.

  **Cons:** It'll be slow.
- Use a LiveCD.

  **Pros:** Most straightforward, same method as when you first installed Ubuntu.

  **Cons:** No persistence of session, your environment is lost when you restart.
- Install on a separate machine. CD read times are sloooow.

  **Pros:** Persistence, speed.

  **Cons:** Expensive if you don't have the hardware.

Personally, I'd go the VM route. You'll need to do with a LiveCD or physical install if your bug involves the hardware.

Comment: Instead of the CD, I suggest using an USB stick instead. You can create a bootable USB stick from a Live CD iso with System-->Administration-->Create a USB startup disk

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what bug you're trying to re-test.  For almost all bugs, testing in a VM is great.  As mentioned on [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108/how-can-i-best-retest-a-bug-in-a-newer-or-development-release/114#114), Testdrive is good for that.

For hardware related bugs you'll need to run on the real hardware, which means that a LiveCD is a more appropriate method.

Answer (score 2):

I depends on what kind of bug it was (estethic, a program crash, etc) but the simplest way would be to download Lucid's live cd, boot it and see if you can reproduce the bug.

If it's something that requires a real installation and it's not enough booting a live cd, then install Lucid on a virtual machine using VirtualBox, and you can test almost anything in there without affecting your current environment.

Answer (score 1):

Without upgrading? You may need to setup a Virtual instance of Lucid or Maverick or install that specific version under a new partition on your machine. I find that VirtualBox works well (and is free) for Ubuntu.